# Angular 12 NullInjectorError

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey guys in Angular 12 I was implementing the following package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login

However I get the following error:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[SocialAuthService -> SocialAuthService -> SocialAuthService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for SocialAuthService!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:11081)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11247)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11247)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11247)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25341)
    at Object.get (core.js:25055)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3342)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3454)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14714)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.LoginComponent_Factory [as factory] (login.component.ts:12)
```

**Ngmodule**

```
import { SocialLoginModule, SocialAuthServiceConfig } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      ...
    ],
    imports: [
      ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: "SocialAuthServiceConfig",
            useValue: {
                autoLogin: false,
                providers: [
                    {
                        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
                            "abc"
                        ),
                    }
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Login module:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SocialAuthService } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";


@Component({
    selector: "app-login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public authService: SocialAuthService) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {}

    signInWithGoogle(): void {
        this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    }

    signOut(): void {
        this.authService.signOut();
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you imported `SocialLoginModule`?

Comment: Yes see my ngmodule

Comment: Mm it seems that I needed to add     providers: [SocialAuthService], in login component. I  usually don't have to do this with services. Any one has an idea why? Please post your answer

Comment: What's in the `imports: []` array?